# Cylindrical Wiener processes or SPDE that can make use of Banach valued rough paths?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-paths

Rough paths theory has an often advertised perk that it mostly works for general Banach spaces. I am trying to think of some nice examples that actually use this feature, and am coming up stuck.

The starting example of a rough path is often $V = \mathbb{R}^d$, and $\boldsymbol{W} = (W, \mathbb{W})$ where $\mathbb{W} \in V \otimes V$ is either Ito or Stratonovich integrals of the components of $W^i$ w.r.t $W^j$.

My basic guess was that I could do something like take $V = \ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ and this would be like an "infinite vector" of Brownian motions. Then I would have an "infinite matrix" defined by componentwise Ito or Stratonovich integrals.

This, at least on the surface level, reminded me of cylindrical Brownian motions that are defined as a convergent sum over an orthonormal basis of some Hilbert space. However, I cannot find immediately related concepts in the literature.

Friz-Hairer talk about transport and linear second order SPDE with $\mathbb{R}^d$ rough paths, and then seem to move on to using the space time white noise $\xi$ and regularity structures soon after. Is trying to leverage $V$ to be infinite dimensional in this direction not a productive venture? If so, are there any interesting uses of infinite dimensional rough paths and their associated RDE?